# What makes LiveCDs, LiveDVDs, and LiveUSBs slow?

Tags: live-usb, performance, live-cd, livedvd

Even on a rather good computer, booting from a LiveCDs or LiveDVDs is really slow, especially in the beginning before the operating system has completely loaded in.

What is the major bottleneck in this case? Reading from the optical disk? The initial decompressing of the file system?

I don't have a speed comparison, so I'm not sure if they are faster, but do LiveUSBs share the same bottlenecks? Or do they have other things working against them?

Comment: Basically, the speed of rotation of optical media, which is between 200 and 500 RPM. That is a lot slower then HDDs that usually spin 5400, 7200, or 10000 RPM.

Answer (score 3):

All this iso images contains a [squashfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) image of the file system. Bevor the start it will be copied into the RAM. In most cases this is the slowest part of booting a LiveCD.

SquashFS Image file for Ubuntu 14.04.1 64 Bit:
984MB

CD/DVD:
21,12 MB/s - Reading speed

USB 2.0:
32MB/s - Reading speed

It takes 04 minutes and 17 seconds to copy the squashfs file into the ram from a usb device. And it takes 06 minutes and 33 seconds to copy it from a cd/dvd.

Extracting of the squashfs File you can easy test by calling the following commands:

```
wget http://mirror.23media.de/ubuntu-releases/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
unzip ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
unsquashfs casper/filesystem.squashfs
```